# Find the number of $4$-digit numbers that can be formed using $1,2,3,4,5$ if no digit is repeated. How many of these will be even?

Tags: permutations

I'm unable to solve this question. Please help. I have no idea. The given answers are $120$ and $48$.  I got $120$ but not $48$. This is how I got $120$.

---

No repetition allowed, so $5\times4\times3\times2=120$ ways.

Comment: What is the criterion for the number to be even?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy suppose a four digit number which is to be made from digits $1,2,3,4,5$.
In thousandth place possible number adjusted is $5$.
In hundredth place possible number adjusted is $4$. Repetition is not allowed.
In tens place possible number adjusted is $3$.
In ones place possible number adjusted is $2$.
Total no is $5×4×3×2=120$.
For even number 
Even number has unit digit $2$ or $4$
So in ones place possible number adjusted is $2$.
In thousandth place possible number adjusted is $4$.
In hundredth place possible number adjusted is $3$.
In tens place possible number adjusted is $2$.
Total even no. is $2×4×3×2=48$.

Answer (score 0):

The ones digit has to be 2 or 4 (as it has to be even). That makes 2 choices. 
These 2 choices are chosen among 5 other choices.

> Therefore, the answer should be $\frac{2}{5}\times5\times4\times3\times2 = 48$